Can the past tense be used to describe events that happened after the moment of utterance?
Suppose there are two events in what you are going to say. For example, in the listening part of an exam:

In this section, you will hear two long conversations. At the end of each conversation, you will hear four questions about what was said.

or

I'm going to tell you some news. Tell me how you feel after I said (?) it/after you heard it.

Should the past tense ("was said" & "said/heard") be used in these examples instead of the simple present or the future perfect?
If the use of tense here is correct, does it mean that the past tense can also describe events that happen in the future, since the recording of the conversation has not been played yet?
If so, is the choice of tense determined by the order of the two events in what you say, or by the order of each events in relation to the time you say the sentence?
By the way, I'm aware that the preterite is sometimes used in the subjunctive mood, but I think that is a different case.

This is a recording of a past event. Do not confuse the time of the playing of the recording, with the actual time of the event.

@fev What if it is not recorded but is instead said on the spot? I added another example. Am I still confusing anything now?

The future perfect sounds insane here - it's a tense that's very rarely used in English. Would you really prefer "At the end of each conversation, you will hear four questions about what will have been said."?

@StuartF No, I wouldn't! But I'm wondering which tense is the best and why.

The second example you give is really unidiomatic. A native might say "Tell me how you feel after you hear the news."

@fev You mean people would use the present tense (hear).

This is the normal tense used in temporal clauses introduced by after, when, as soon as etc. Will have said would be hypercorrect in your sentence, that is, it may respect the grammatical rule, but is never used in common language.

I would say"Tell me how you feel when you've heard it".

The first example seems fine to me. "what was said" is in the past tense because it's relative to the future time indicated by "At the end of the conversation" and "you will hear".
In the second example, it's still appropriate to use past tense, but it feels more idiomatic to use past perfect: "after [I have said / you have heard] it".
I'm not sure what the difference is that requires the perfect mode in the second case.

The use of tenses is clear but have, as so often in English, loosened up in time.  You are quite right that the present tense refers to the time of utterance and the future tense tense is usually used for events after the time of utterance.  But there is a special tense, the Future Perfect, which is used in cases which involve three events, a (the statement) b (an event predicted by a) and c (an event predicted as coming in the future (with respect to a) but in the past with respect to a.  That is the Future Perfect, a tense that exists in many/most European languages.
So, strictly speaking, following the above, the student would hear:

"In this section, you will hear two long conversations.


At the end of each conversation, you will hear four questions about what WILL HAVE BEEN said.

This is because in relation to the examinee reading the instruction the recorded conversation will be in the future but in relation to the the four questions, the recorded conversation will be in the past.  So the the Future Perfect is the the more precise tense to use:  it's what it is for.
However, it can be argued that, in common English usage, the Future Perfect Tense is fading out and that the strictly 'correct' Future Perfect tense can be replaced by the Simple Perfect tense with "..have rather than will have heard").  The "after you heard it", using the English equivalent of the Aorist, seems to go too far, creating a clash between orders of the two events.  The compromise is to use the simple perfect (with have), which need not cause confusion or discomfort for the listener/reader.  English is constantly in flux in this way.
The second example also poses a problem.  The "...after you heard it" goes a little too far

What will have been said is wrong here. English speakers interpret the past tense in that sentence as meaning something previous to "you will hear two long conversations, and not something previous to the present.

I am not sure I understand you.  the order of events is  1) the testee's explanation of the test; 2)  the "long conversation"  3)four questions about 2) followed by 2a) - a different long conversation and 3a) the four different questions about 3.  So in relation to 1, 2 and 2a, and 3 and 3a are all in the future.  But for each of 2a and 3a each can only be true when 2 and 3 have already happened and so are in the past.  So by the time 3 happens, 2 WILL (in relation to 1) already HAVE (in relation to 2) happened: future perfect.
